# Defintion of strictly concave

Tags: proof-writing, convex-analysis

How do I show that if a function satisfies

$f(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y) > \alpha f(x) + (1-\alpha)f(y)$ with $0 < \alpha < 1$,

it is true that (assuming it exists) the second derivative

$f''(x) < 0$.

I can see this is true visually in a graph but a more rigourous proof is elusive.

EDIT: I see a counterexample in the comment. I have now corrected the errors in my question (mixed up strictly concave and concave) and broadly ask about when I can use the second derivative to prove concavity (as is done to show $\log(x)$ is concave for instance) and how the equivalence is shown in these cases.

Comment: It's not true. For instance, if $f(x)=-x^4$, then $f$ is strictly concave, but $f''(0)=0$.

Comment: @TonyK: your comment should be an answer in my opinion.

Comment: a linear function satisfies your first 'definition' but is not strictly concave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes if we assume that $f''(x) < 0$ esists then $f(x)$ is strictly concave but if  $f(x)$ is strictly concave we can also have  $f''(x) \le 0$ with $f''(x)=0$ is some points (not on an interval) as for example $f(x)=-x^4$.

For the proof the idea behind is to show that

- $f''(x)<0 \implies f'(x)$ strictly decreasing $\iff f(x)$ strictly concave
- $f(x)$ concave$ \iff f'(x)$ decreasing $\iff f''(x)\le0$

Comment: Thank you - could you add a short bit about the equivalence between concave and $f'(x)$ decreasing? This is "visually obvious" but I would like to understand it more rigorously than that

Comment: Ah I see this can be done using the mean value theorem. Thank you!

Comment: @user1936752 Yes indeed MVT is the key to show that. Refer also to the related [OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2824874/505767).